# Execute postgres function on server from local

Tags: linux, ssh, postgresql

I've a postgres database on server. There is an upsert function which takes a file as an input. Is there any way to execute the upsert function from my local without having to scp the file to server and upsert it there?

(I'm trying to automate the whole process. It'll be easier if I can upsert it directly from my local instead of doing scp and then ssh etc.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From what you said, I guess your database doesn't allow external connections so, basicaly, **nope**, you cannot do anything remotely directly to the database.